# XFinium PDF library mobile: How to get height of a wrapped text

Tags: android, pdf, mobile, text

We are using XFinium PDF library to generate a PDF document from a mobile device. We are using the code example for writing a wrapped text as below:

```
    PdfStringAppearanceOptions sao = new PdfStringAppearanceOptions();
    sao.Brush = brush;
    sao.Font = helvetica;

    // Height is not set, text has no vertical limit.
    PdfStringLayoutOptions slo = new PdfStringLayoutOptions();
    slo.HorizontalAlign = PdfStringHorizontalAlign.Justified;
    slo.VerticalAlign = PdfStringVerticalAlign.Top;
    slo.X = 20;
    slo.Y = 70;
    slo.Width = 280;
    string text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. " +
        "Sed vel euismod risus. Fusce viverra, nisi auctor ullamcorper porttitor, " +
        "ipsum lacus lobortis metus, sit amet dictum lacus velit nec diam. " +
        "Morbi arcu diam, euismod a auctor nec, aliquam in lectus." +
        "Ut ultricies iaculis augue sit amet adipiscing. Aenean blandit tortor a nisi " +
        "dignissim fermentum id adipiscing mauris. Aenean libero turpis, varius nec ultricies " +
        "faucibus, pretium quis lectus. Morbi mollis lorem vel erat condimentum mattis mollis " +
        "nulla sollicitudin. Nunc ut massa id felis laoreet feugiat eget at eros.";
    page.Graphics.DrawString(text, sao, slo);
```

However, how do we draw another string below this if we don't know what the next y coordinate will be? Is there a way to calculate the height of an existing text or a way to find out what thenext available y coordinate will be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The Xfinium.Pdf.Graphics.Text.PdfTextEngine class includes the static method GetStringHeight(string s, PdfFont font, double width). Pass in the string you want to draw, the font used for drawing the string and the width where the text will wrap and the method will return the height of the wrapped 
text.
For your code fragment the call looks like this:

```
double textHeight = PdfTextEngine.GetStringHeight(text, helvetica, slo.Width);
```

Disclaimer: I work for the company that develops XFINIUM.PDF library.

Comment: PdfTextEngine doesn't seem to be available in the latest version of the library.

Comment: Add `using Xfinium.Pdf.Graphics.Text;` to get access to PdfTextEngine